# Recommended books for Beltrami-Klein Disk :

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry

I am looking for good books to study the Beltrami-Klein Disk in Hyperbolic geometry because most of books that I have discuss just the Poicaré half plane, the Poincaré disk. I want that the book contains isometries, the mobius transformations in the klein disk (if they exists)  geodesics, metric, distance, angles ...
Any help is really appreciated !

Comment: The phrase "Möbius transformations" refers specifically to the functions in either the Poincaré half plane or Poincaré disc that represent isometries of the hyperbolic plane. The isometries in the Klein disc model are *not* Möbius transformations.

Comment: Thank you so much sir ! It is very useful , especiaally the book "Geometry and Topology of Manifolds: Surfaces and Beyond
".